# Extend memory alocated to java application

Tags: java

I've java application that returns error out of heap space, I've found that I should add -Xmx flag when starting appliaction. I changed shortcut file property target from "C:\app_dir\app.exe" to "C:\app_dir\app.exe"-Xmx3g (I need 3GB or more). But application returns that cannot initialize Java loader. I've changed settings in Java applet in control panel, adding to JRE parameters -Xmx3g, but nothing has changed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: make it a 64-bit application

Comment: It would be hard to compile app without sources.